# python code about transfer text file to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

The aim is making dictionary from words of a file. So I defined the following function for open and read file, then make a list with words of a file. I test the function and it works properly, but when I call it for transfer the list to dictionary, the full dictionary is not achieved.

```
fild = dict()
def file2word():

    fname = input("Enter a file name: ")
    try:
        fhand = open(fname)
    except:
        print("File cannot open",fname)
        exit()  
    count = 0
    val = list()
    for line in fhand:
        li = line.split()
        val = val + li
        count = count + 1
    return(val)

i = 0
lst = file2word()
while True:
    x = lst.pop(i)
    fild[x] = "done" 
    if i == len(lst):break

print(fild)
```

Comment: I am sorry but i did not understand what are you trying to achieve. I tested your code with a file of mine and it worked well. Are you trying to create a dictionary ( word: number of times it appears) ?

Comment: thanks for your consideration, I want to create a dictionary, the value of the keys is not important, but the concluded dictionary is not complete, it is made by just the first line of my text file. I could not understand what problem is...

Comment: Oh, can you try the code that is showed on your post? I edited. I think your problem was that the "return(val)" was inside the loop.

Comment: It works well... I appreciated you.